# Cannot POST to my Mysql database using my HTML registration form: UPDATED CODE

Tags: php, html, mysql

so im trying to create a registration form for my website and am using a SQL database using phpmyadmin. I have done a ton of research on how to create the PHP file that will add the User to my database after creating their account. To the best of my knowledge, i have the correct execution and code but when i go to my website, create a user and go to my phpmyadmin to check my database table to see if the user is created..it is not.Below i will include my code for connection php file along with my register.php file. At this point i have no idea as to what is wrong with my code that is not actually POSTing and data to the database after creating an account on my website.

**Below is my UPDATED dbconnect.php file which is included in my register.php**

```
    <?php 

/*** mysql hostname ***/
$hostname = 'localhost';
/*** mysql username ***/
$username = '******';
/*** mysql password ***/
$password = '******';



try {
function testdb_connect (){
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=*******", $username, $password);
return ($dbh);
}
$dbh = testdb_connect();
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

**Here is the UPDATED PHP section of register.php:**

```
      <?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['User']))
{
 header("Location: home.php");
}
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$uname = $_POST['uname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$upass = $_POST['upass'];

}
 $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as `emailcount` FROM `User` WHERE email=:email");
 $stmt->execute(array("email" => $_POST['email']));
 $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if ($row['emailcount'] > 0) {
    echo "<script>alert('Email $email already exists in our system. Please try another email')</script>";
}


    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO User(`uname`, `email`, `upass`) VALUES (:uname, :email, :upass)");

    $stmt->execute(array("uname" => $_POST['uname'], "email" => $_POST['email'], "upass" => md5($_POST['upass'])));






?>
```

**And here is the  UPDATED HTML form which creates the user account and is supposed to POST to my database table:**

```
    <form method='post' action='register.php'>
                <pre>
                <div>
            <label>Name : (letters only)*</label>
<input type="text" name="uname" pattern="[A-Za-z]+" title="only letters" required />
</div>

<div>
<label>E-mail : (xyz@zyx.com)*</label>
<input type="email" name="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" title="xyz@something.com" required />
</div>


<div>
<label>password : (at least 6 chars)</label>
<input type="password" name="upass" pattern=".{6,}" title="Six or more characters" required />
</div>



<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Sign Up'>
</pre>
</form>
```

Comment: In your code `$uname`, `$email` and `$umail` are commented? Is it really like that in your code? Also, in your form you use `upass` and you tried to get `$_POST['pass']`

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of things here that needs to be altered, let's start with your choice of API.

**Mixing APIs and addressing prepared statements**

This isn't something you can do in PHP. Your connection uses PDO, while your queries used the *old and outdated* `mysql_*` functions. I'd recommend you edit your code to reflect the connection rather than change the connection to the deprecated `mysqli_*`. You should also use prepared statements.

So instead of the line `$run = mysql_query($check_email);`, you'd do something like this, which will use the API you chose in your connection-code, and take advantage of prepared statements.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as `emailcount` FROM `User` WHERE email=:email");
$stmt->execute(array("email" => $_POST['email']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if ($row['emailcount'] > 0) {
    echo "<script>alert('Email $email already exists in our system. Please try another email')</script>";
}
```

And your insertion query would look something like this:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO User(`uname`, `email`, `upass`) VALUES (:uname, :email, :pass)");
$stmt->execute(array("uname" => $_POST['uname'], "email" => $_POST['email'], "pass" => md5($_POST['upass'])));
```

Also note that you used `name="upass"` in your form, but your PHP used `$_POST['pass']`, which are different, and they need to be the same.

**Calling the function for your connection**

In your connection file, you put the PDO object inside a function, which is fine, but you need to call it, either after you require the file, or in the connection file itself.

```
$dbh = testdb_connect();
```

EDIT: Per the comments, also discovered another issue with the variable-scope:

You're also facing some issues with *variable scope*, as you define the variables for your connection outside the function. The function can't see those variables, because they are not defined inside the function, passed as arguments or made global.

I strongly recommend you not use `global` variables, and instead pass them as arguments or define them inside the function. This example below have been modified to define them inside the function instead.

```
<?php 
// Define a function for the PDO object
function testdb_connect() {
    try {
        /*** mysql hostname ***/
        $hostname = 'localhost';
        /*** mysql username ***/
        $username = '--------';
        /*** mysql password ***/
        $password = '------';

        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=databasename", $username, $password);
        return $dbh;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

$dbh = testdb_connect(); // call the function, create the connection
?>
```

The errors you provided in the comments suggests that the object was not created, which should now be fixed with the above code. I also restructured it a bit, putting the try/catch block in a more appropriate place.

**Your submit-button**

This is mainly why nothing happened. Your submit-button has no name, attribute, but two values instead. Which means that the line `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` will never be true, because there is no input-element with that name.

Instead of

```
<input type='submit' value='submit' value='Sign Up'>
```

it should look like

```
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Sign Up'>
```

**False positives with `isset`**

The line `if(isset($_SESSION['User'])!="")` would give you a false positive, as an `isset()` returns a boolean (true/false), which will never be equal to an empty string.

It should be `if (isset($_SESSION['User'])) {`, which will redirect the user only if he is signed in.

**Additional notes**

With the changes above, your checks for empty email/password should be slightly changed, as we will no longer need the lines you commented out (as those use the old `mysql_real_escape_string()` and we'll be using PDO instead, so they are not defined):

```
if (empty($_POST['uname'])) {
    echo "<script>alert('Please Enter Your name')</script>";
    exit();
}
if (empty($_POST['email '])) {
    echo "<script>alert('Please Enter Your Email')</script>";
    exit();
}
```

- Your password-hashing is `md5`, which is discouraged to use with passwords. You should look into using a function such as [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) instead.
- Enable [`error_reporting(E_ALL);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) when troubleshooting

**Additional reading-material**

- [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)
- [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942)

Comment: Thank you so much for such a thorough comment and assistance. I have taken all of your advice and changed my code around to fit what you suggested. Although now i am getting two errors when i load my register.php page which i wasnt getting before. And yet..still the form doesnt POST to my database after creating an account. The error i get is the following:

Comment: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'nobody'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/adelphistudys/public_html/register.php on line 23

Comment: If you dont mind just looking at my original post i edited all the code to fit the new updated one so you can see what i have changed since the original version.

Comment: @BC0148 I've updated my answer, specifically under "*Calling the function for your connection*", have a read at that :-)

Comment: Also, just noticed in your update, your `if ($row['emailcount'] > 0) {` is somewhat too early in the code - it needs to be after the query has been executed (below `$row = $stmt->fecth();`). -- and `if(mysql_query($sql)){` is no longer needed, and will cause warnings/errors, you can just remove that.

Comment: thank you, i have edited my dbconnect.php file to be exactly as you have updated it to be. and that section of register.php now looks like this

  }
 $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as `emailcount` FROM `User` WHERE email=:email");
 $stmt->execute(array("email" => $_POST['email']));
 $row = $stmt->fecth();

if ($row['emailcount'] > 0) {
    echo "<script>alert('Email $email already exists in our system. Please try another email')</script>";
}

Comment: But now i am getting this error : 
Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::fecth() in /home/adelphistudys/public_html/register.php on line 24

Comment: Haha, sorry, I've miss-spelled the word :P And you can add a constant to that value, so make it `$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` instead :-)

Comment: YES! thank you so much its working now. I was able to create a user. It also created a NULL uname and NULL email also. Why would that be

Comment: Because you tried using variables which aren't defined, like I mentioned in the answer above. You have commented out the lines which defines them -- but if you un-comment them you will get warnings too, because you're using `mysql_real_escape_string` on them. You can instead just replace those commented lines with `$uname = $_POST['uname'];`

Comment: if i replace those commented lines with that, when i go to make a user it doesnt create any user it just creates a NULL all across the row on the table. Before it was creating the NULL and the actual username. What went wrong here >.<

Comment: I will edit my original post to reflect the php part of register.php that i have changed

Comment: @BC0148 The `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` should be wrapped about all the queries, because now you will insert even if there is no data submitted, leading to NULL being inserted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to uncomment this:

```
$uname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$upass = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']));
```

Answer (score -1):

check post value of password field....& update it by $upass = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['upass']));

Answer (score -1):

possible error apart form commented lines

1: is `databasename` your database name

2: PHP version > 5.5.0

3: input field `has an escaped character` and db setting dosnt accept `NULL` as value

```
dont use mysql_real_escape_string***
```

Answer (score -2):

```html
<input type="password" name="upass" pattern=".{6,}" title="Six or more characters" required/>
```

Since the name of input type password is 'upass', then you should assign 'upass' to your $upass variable. or change the name of input type to 'pass'.

It should be like this after submitting form

```html
$upass = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['upass']));
```